# Fedora system computer wifi is enabled but can't detect any network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, fedora

My fedora computer can't seems to detect any wifi available. I just installed broadcom driver and wifi is on. But no network detected. However, I can connect to ethernet lan. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Recent Fedoras does not need any drivers for most of current hw. I suspect that Broadcom driver is doing the harm here.

Download & boot [Fedora live](http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/20/Live/i386/Fedora-Live-Xfce-i686-20-1.iso) (or [32-bit](http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/20/Live/i386/Fedora-Live-Xfce-i686-20-1.iso) if you are running old hw) from usb and try the wifi from it.

Comment: Hi @andrej i have already installed the latest version of fedora. Yes, i suspect it is broadcom. may I know how to rectify this issue?

Comment: You have to detect what module is yuor system trying to use with that broadcom thing. Use `sudo dmesg | grep -i broadcom` or `sudo dmesg | less` and find for "broadcom" or "wireless" or similar strings. I've got intel hw here so my dmesg line is `[  126.957477] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux` and the iwl3945 is the module involved. Try to google for [your module name] and fedora to find more - you are probably not alone with this kind of problem.